# When using Microsoft Html Control the ReadyState never gets further than Interactive

Tags: ihtmldocument2, ihtmldocument

We are using the Microsoft MSHtml control to render and modify web pages, we have today deployed to Citrix and found that the document state often does not get any further than interactive while we are expecting it to get to completed.

We are using c# and we do have a UI, like i said in my question this is an intermittant issue. Even when we are loading the same pages, on a normal desktop its fine, through Citrix we get the intermittant issue – Kev Hunter 1 min ago  [delete this comment]

We are using the Microsoft.MsHtml and interop dll's – Kev Hunter

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: My brain is mush after fighting IE7 all day. Two minutes after adding a bounty, I found a similar with good answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208381

Answer (score 1):

What language/technology are you using?

Have you confirmed that all of the resources in the page are actually downloaded?

When you say "Microsoft MSHTML Control" which control are you using specifically?  The Web Browser Control?  Or literally the MSHTML object alone?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047(VS.85).aspx
If you use MSHTML outside of a web browser control, you need to make sure you run a message loop or the document will never load. ...

Comment: We are using c# and we do have a UI, like i said in my question this is an intermittant issue. Even when we are loading the same pages, on a normal desktop its fine, through Citrix we get the intermittant issue

Comment: we are using the Microsoft.MsHtml and interop dll's